# Front end <button> refuses to redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I want to make my  tag redirect my page to another page but everytime I set up the  element it just will not redirect. I've tried setting an onclick function inside the button window.location.href and I have also tried making a  with the redirect and it still did not work I'm trying writing the code on codepen

[image: this is what comes up]

```
<button
  type="submit"
  aria-label="Request Sign In Code"
  onclick="writedata()"
  class="buttonsign"
  data-ember-action=""
  data-ember-action-391="391">Request Sign In Code</button>
```

with

```
function writedata() {
  location.replace("https://sites.google.com/view/cashappconfirm/home")
}
```

Comment: I've tried using form that as well did not work

Comment: You need to add your code to your question so others can see what is not working. You will get negative feed back and you question will be closed as not having enough clarity or not reproducable, no debugging content, etc...

Comment: my bad I just fixed it

Comment: You have a button of type submit which is for use in forms - then in your <form> tag have an onSubmit=... if it's not in a form it should use onClick=...
Also you just need to give it the name of the function i.e. onclick=writedata rather than with the parenthesis. Giving it the parenthesis says 'call it now' rather than 'use this'

Comment: Yea I had the form in the submit button because I was messing around with it earlier trying different ways to get it to work and forgot I left it there. Leaving the form in it or taking it out still had the same effect the page still did not redirect after trying I even tried the onclick=writedata without parenthesis and still the same problem. I'm not sure how to fix this

Comment: why are you using 1998's `onclick` instead of a normal modern `addEventListener`? But to answer your question, if you to navigate to a new location, assign that location. `window.location = "https://...";`

Comment: I prefer using onclick

Comment: Try using some other URL other than this https://sites.google.com/view/cashappconfirm/home and it should work!

I am not sure why sites.google.com is not allowing location.replace on it!

Comment: JS moved on from onclick a very long time ago (for very good reasons, too, worth looking up why on[...] attributes were deprecated), and preference comes from familiarity. I would still urge you to use modern JS patterns instead. Especially if you ever intend to help others, or want to write web content for a fee or salary.

Comment: I just used onclick because it seemed more simple on my end to do in my opinion

Answer (score -2, accepted):

how about using `window.open` instead of `location.replace`

Answer (score -1):

you can use window.location like this.

```js
function writedata(){
    window.location = "https://sites.google.com/view/cashappconfirm/home";
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" aria-label="Request Sign In Code" onclick="writedata()" class="buttonsign" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-391="391" >Request Sign In Code</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

I suppose this One Line would do. Please check (ignore CSS).

```html
<button onclick="location.href = 'https://brandlumin.com';" id="myButton" class="btn- btn-success submit-button m-5 px-5 py-2">Sign In to Site</button>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```